# Google workspace SSO authentication with .NET Core

Tags: .net, .net-core, google-oauth, single-sign-on, saml

We are trying to build a new application with Google authentication. Here we have to authenticate user credential using google workspace SAML token.

Don't want to use google OAuth from Google cloud. We want to implement this in .NET Core project. Couldn't find any good documentation for .NET technology.

Tried a few things, but didn't work properly. I need help or suggestions to solve this problem.

Comment: The only way to sign in a user is to use oauth2. Service accounts Arnt for sign-in they are for server to server pre-authorized access